# When i try to validate xml file using DocumentBuilderFactory by schema i recieve error "Cannot find the declaration of element "

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, domparser

i have xml file that's named input.xml

it contaits following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tests xmlns="http://www.example.com/Report"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/Report input.xsd">
    <test id="1">
        <coverage>65</coverage>
        <usedFramework>Junit4</usedFramework>
        <typeTest>Integration</typeTest>
    </test>
    <test id="2">
        <coverage>35</coverage>
        <usedFramework>Junit5</usedFramework>
        <typeTest>Module</typeTest>
    </test>
    <test id="3">
        <coverage>45</coverage>
        <usedFramework>Mockito</usedFramework>
        <typeTest>Integration</typeTest>
    </test>
</tests>
```

Also I have XML Schema that has name input.std
XML Schema file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/Report"
           xmlns="http://www.example.com/Report"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="tests">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="test" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="coverage" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                            <xs:element name="usedFramework" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="typeTest" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Next code will be written on java

```
try {
          File schemaFile = new File("input.xsd");
            SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
                    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
                Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);

            File inputXml = new File(xmlPath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
            factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
            factory.setSchema(schema);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(inputXml);
            List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
            NodeList tests = document.getElementsByTagName("test");
            for(int i=0;i< tests.getLength();i++){
                Element element = (Element) tests.item(i);
                if(element.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    int coverage = Integer.parseInt(element.getElementsByTagName("coverage").item(0).getTextContent());
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(element.getAttribute("id"));
                    String usedFramework = (element.getElementsByTagName("usedFramework").item(0).getTextContent());
                    String typeTest = (element).getElementsByTagName("typeTest").item(0).getTextContent();
                    list.add(new Test(id,coverage,usedFramework,typeTest));
                }
            }
            list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Test::getCoverage));
            list.forEach(System.out::println);

        }catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e){
            
            Logger.getLogger(XmlReader.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO,e.getMessage());

        }
```

when i'm trying to run application Error occurs
[image]

So Where did I go wrong?I looked "How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?" on different question and didn't see any mistakes, could you help me fix them?

Comment: Please try to provide a fully qualified path for both input XML file as well as schema in your code.

Comment: In your description, you have 'input._std_' and in your code, it is 'input._xsd_'. Is it just a typo? And are you sure the path is correct? Maybe it is stored under 'resources/input.xsd', for instance?

Comment: I have already found mistake. I must invoke DocumentBuilderFactory's method setNamespaceAware and pass true as parametr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to invoke DocumentBuilderFactory's method setNamespaceAware and pass true as parametr

```
// parse an XML document into a DOM tree
DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.parse(new File("example.xml"));
```

The problem was that DocumentBuilder is not namespace aware by default. The following additional change resolved the issue:

```
// parse an XML document into a DOM tree
DocumentBuilderFactory dmfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dmfactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder parser = dmfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.parse(new File("example.xml"));
```